# How long does a snapshot take to complete in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, snapshot

I have to create a RDS snapshot, and for planning purposes I would like to know how long it could take to complete.
I have some snapshots lying around in my AWS account but I cannot find any details about the duration their took to finish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on the size. Why not make a snapshot and check?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, It a productive environment and I cannot make snapshot as I am pleased. I was just wondering if that information can be seen on some details page.

Comment: There are no official benchmarks. Don't you have any testing account to test on some dummy instance? But usually the first snapshot takes much longer then subsequent ones, as they are incremental, not full.

Comment: Test account ist not an option as the prod db is generally much bigger, but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an informative answer re. how Snapshots work under the hood which should ease your concern, https://serverfault.com/questions/919533/rds-snapshot-how-long-does-i-o-suspension-occur